# Invoking Transaction controller or HTTP sampler from Bean shell/JSR223

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223, jmeter-3.2

**Problem statement.**
Set of transactions(1000+) and need to call or reuse(without duplicating in different if/switch controllers) by invoking from the Beanshell or JSR233.

In SoapUI we have groovy script option to break sequential execution and divert control to any  request using the below command.

```
if( Math.random() > 0.5 )
   testRunner.runTestStepByName( "Request 1")
else
   testRunner.runTestStepByName( "Request 2")

// do something else
....
```

Same functionality available in Loadrunner(Run time setting with different action) and neoload too.

**Do we have any built-in objects or function to execute by transaction or Sampler name from JSR223/BeanShell without using if/while/switch controller** ?

For Example:

In script 10 transactions are there and to use same script for different scenario by setting a JMeter property during execution through Jenkins or command prompt .

```
__P(Flow,RoomBooking)
```

Then from JSR233 /beanshell sampler

```
if(Flow=="RoomBooking"){

invoke Login 

invoke BookRoom

invoke Logout

} else if(Flow=="RoomBookingNBookItinerary")

invoke Login 

invoke BookRoom

invoke BookItinerary

invoke Logout

}else if(Flow=="RoomBookingNcancel")

invoke Login 

invoke BookRoom

Invoke ParkTicket 

invoke CancelRoom

invoke Logout

}Like different flows with different thread and throughput
```

In this case I can mix and match different flows and and reuse same script for different flow. 
This would help to reduce script rework effort during application changes.

Comment: I answered, if my understanding of your question is not clear, please show an example test plan in JMeter and SoapUI and how it would work in SoapUI

Comment: Module Controller can include if statement so why not using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, JMeter doesn't have JSR 223 Logic Controller at all,

I think that it can help changing also the if controller,

I suggest you open an [enhancement](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=JMeter) to JMeter product (choose Severity:  enhancement)

**EDIT**

There's a new [Bug 61711 - Add JSR223 Logic Controller](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61711) you can [vote](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/page.cgi?id=voting/user.html&bug_id=61711#vote_61711) on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to execute a previous sampler one more time from the JSR223 Script it would be something like:

```
ctx.getPreviousSampler().sample(null)
```

where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) for all available methods and fields.

Demo:

[image: JSR223 Execute Sampler One more Time]

---

However a better idea would be using JMeter's [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) which allows executing a part of JMeter test plan somewhere else, this way you can implement a form of [`goto` statement in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/easily-write-a-goto-statement-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly do it with [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)

[image: Test Plan]

Any step will be a [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller)

And in a [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) you'll set which step you want:

[image: JSR223 Sampler]

Comment: It wouldn’t help, that’s y I specified  without if/switch/while controller and have more than 1000+ transactions.  I just want to break the linear execution and use goto with help of groovy or beanshell

Comment: In this case , can you just illustrate with an example please by editing your question ?